# Como retornar um valor lógico quando as linhas tem valores idênticos no software R?

Tags: r

Eu tenho um banco de dados que contém 3 variáveis: `var1`, `var2` e `var 3`. Eu tentei usar algumas funções no R que me retornassem um valor lógico caso alguma das linha tivessem os mesmos valores. Uma delas foi a função `all`, conforme abaixo:

```
apply(meusdados,1,all)
```

Porém, notei que ela retorna `TRUE` apenas para valores diferentes de `0` se há repetição.

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Aléḿ disso, esta função não funciona com vetores com caracteres, retornando tudo `NA`.

Como corrigir isto, de forma que se as linhas idênticas retornem o valor boolean `TRUE`?

Meus dados com as variáveis númericas são estes:

```
structure(list(var1 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), var2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), var3 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0)), .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3"), class = "data.frame",  row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Com as strings, são estes:

```
structure(list(var1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("compras", "opfin"), class = "factor"), 
var2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("compras", "opfin"), class = "factor"), var3 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("compras", 
"opfin"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("var1", "var2", 
"var3"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função seguinte resolve o problema tanto para dados numéricos (`dados1`) como para dados não numéricos, por exemplo de classe `character` (`dados2`).

```
todosIguais <- function(DF){
  apply(DF, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)
}

todosIguais(dados1)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

todosIguais(dados2)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Para checar se um mesmo elemento se repete em todas as colunas use a condição `> 1`, caso queira checar se um elemento se repete ao menos uma vez nas colunas use a condição `== 3`. Em ambos os casos a combinação das funções `dim()` e `table()` contabilizará a quantidade de elementos distintos por linha.

```
chec_rep_rows = function(data){
  data = as.matrix(data)
  for (i in 1:nrow(data))
    print(ifelse(dim(table(data[i,])) > 1, FALSE, TRUE))
}

chec_rep_rows(data)
```